# How To Handle First Time Installation in a Shopify App?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api, shopify-template

There is first time installation sequence that I would like to execute once the user finished installing the app.

Some recommended using afterAuth function with webhooks, but this event is not available in the [documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/webhook)

thanks for helping